# How can I change the white color to random so it's still looking good?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color

I took a photo of some vegetable powders in small glasses. Now I would like to change the white color to blue or any other color (maybe gradient), so the color of the powders doesn't change (of course... :P) and **the new background color would also be noticable on/through glasses.**

Is it possible, to make it look really realistic?

[image: Powder photo.]

Image will be used for a product sale web banner.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to change the background color? I think the white really compliments the rainbow shades.

Comment: Whatever color you choose _will_ have an effect on the perception of the powder colors. The most neutral choices would be black/white or perhaps shades of neutral grey (% pure black).

Answer (score 1):

The most safe way would be avoiding color by manually creating a mask on the powders, either by some color selection or by manually painting the mask. by isolating color information, you will end up transforming the powder in a full-black shape that can be cancelled out as a mask. 
You can do this via selective color or using the selection by color range at the Image > Calculations menu item.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the cast of the background using an adjustment layer. First select the white area and include the clear bowls. Select inverse to mask the spices. I used Selective Color (select Neutrals or Whites) and Channel Mixer each alone changes it slightly different. Play around with the settings until you get the desired effect.

I do not necessarily think these are improvements to the white but it does what you asked. Good luck.

[image: Selective Color]

[image: Channel Mixer]